# Converting points into another coordinate system

Tags: algorithm, matrix, geometry, computational-geometry, rotational-matrices

There are 3 points in 3D space. There are 2 orthogonal coordinate systems with the same origin. I know coordinates of those 3 points in both coordinate systems. Given a new point with its coordinates in the first coordinate system, how can I find its coordinates in the second coordinate system? 
I think it's possible to get a rotation matrix using given points which does this, but I did not succeed doing this.

Comment: Are the coordinate systems unknown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using matrix inverses. Three matrix-vector multiplications (e.g. transforming three 3D vectors by a 3x3 matrix) is equivalent to multiplying two 3x3 matrices together.

So, you can put your first set of points in one matrix, call it A:

```
0 0 1  < vector 1
0 1 0  < vector 2
2 0 0  < vector 3
```

Then put your second set of points in a second matrix, call it C. As an example, imagine a transform that scales by a factor of 2 around the origin and flips the Y and Z axes:

```
0 2 0  < vector 1
0 0 2  < vector 2
4 0 0  < vector 3
```

So, if A x B = C, we need to find the matrix B, which we can find by finding the A<sup>-1</sup>:

Inverse of A:

```
0 0 0.5
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

The multiply A<sup>-1</sup> x C (in that order):

```
2 0 0
0 0 2
0 2 0
```

This is a transform matrix B that you can apply to new points. Dot-product multiply the vector by the first column to get the transformed X, second column to get the transformed Y, etc.

Comment: What if A is not invertible?

Comment: There are going to be some cases where it's not possible to work out the transform: for example of 2 of the points are identical, or if they all lie on a line. Are there any examples where the A is not invertible that correspond to situation where the calculating the transform should be possible?

Comment: Looks like there are 2 bad cases. 1) all 3 points are collinear. 2) all 3 points have y=0 or x=0 or z=0.

Comment: In the case where the points are colinear it's not possible to compute the transform because you can't account for rotation around the line. In the second case I'm not sure what the geometric meaning is - possibly because you can't tell if there is a reflection in the X, Y or Z plane? If you know that the handedness of the before and after co-ordinate systems is the same then you could generate a 4th point (before and after) based on the first 3 using a cross-product that would put it off the plane, and  substitute that for one of the others in A and C.

Comment: In the second case, you do not have three points. You have only one point. This will probably happen whenever all three points are equal. If two points are the same, they will fall into the line case.

Comment: If A is invertible it might be wise to check that it's orthogonal: the rows (or columns) should be normalized (of length 1) and each pair of distinct rows should have dot product 0. If A is not invertible then rows for which dot product with a previous row is nonzero should be eliminated; then the remaining rows can be extended to an orthonormal basis. That should cover all the exceptional cases, I think.